# Initiate a Post request from a form with paylod in the Body request

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem. I have a webservice, which accepts a post request with some json data in the request body and which also returns Json data.
Now I want to build a user friendly HTML page to test this service. I have a form to fill in data, when the user clicks the button, the JSON should be build from the form data and POSTed to my webservice, the response should be displayed to the user. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Tell us more about your HTML please, give some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is your friend, the have a look at ajax part...there a bunch of function that forge a request and grab directly the data from your form.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This is one **example** doing this, but it requires a **MySQL database** and **PHP** support by your provider.

**jQuery**

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.POST('path_to_php_file.php', data, function(response) {
        $('#container').append(response);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASENAME;charset=utf8', USERNAME, PASSWORD);
//the post variables equal the name attribute on your input element in html: <input name="THIS">
$text = $_POST['text'];
$name = $_POST['name']; 
if(isset($text) && isset($name)) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (text, name) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($text, $name));
    echo "Successfully saved.";
} else echo "There was an error.";
$db = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you just want to test your webservice, is to use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), a friendly chrome extension for testing web APIs.

Otherwise, you really don't even need jQuery.  A synchronous post is easy enough to write:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.onclick = function() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "yourwebservice.com/your-web-service", false);
    xhr.send("{'json_string':['goes'],['here']}");        
    alert(xhr.response);

}
```